# How to make Sublime Text 3 handle excluded files like Atom?

Tags: sublime-text-3

In Atom, things in your `.gitignore` are automatically filtered out when you search for files (via <kbd>cmd+P</kbd>/<kbd>cmd+T</kbd>), and they are excluded from things like project-wide find-and-replace.

But they are still visible in your file tree (greyed out so they look less prominent than actual project files, but you can still see them and open them if you want).

I want this exact same behaviour in Sublime Text 3. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this plugin for sublime text 3? https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Gitignored%20File%20Excluder

It excludes files based on .gitignore

Comment: Thanks for the suggeestion, but that just completely hides files from everywhere in ST3, which is exactly what I don't want.